# jQuery animate bump up on hover effect

Tags: jquery

I want the image I hover over to move upwards and back down again when I'm not longer hovering.  I was able to accomplish this effect using CSS3, but since not all browsers support it, I would like to get it working with jQuery as well.  I've created a Fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/fSthA/2/

Here's my jQuery code:

```
$('.full-circle').mouseOver(
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate(
            {margin-top: '2'}, 500, 'swing'   
        );//end animate
    },//end function
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate(
            {margin-top: '15'}, 500, 'swing'
        );//end animate
    }//end function
);//end hover
```

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your question is, but I modified your fiddle to do it via jQuery.  I just had to remove the css transition, the `:hover` style, add jQuery to the fiddle, change your `animate` call to use `marginTop` instead of `margin-top`:

```
$('.full-circle').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate(
            {marginTop: '2'}, 500, 'linear'   
        );//end animate
     },//end function
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate(
            {marginTop: '15'}, 500, 'linear'
        );//end animate
    }//end function
);//end hover
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fSthA/5/

Comment: Changed color to red : http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/fSthA/8/ so the circle is actually visible without squinting :D